# How can I fit in the TD within the table which has huge amount of content

Tags: html, css

Content within the last TD is to be shown and hidden on click of "Click for content".
But the TD isn't fitting within the table. How can this be fixed.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test td 1</td>
    <td>test td 2</td>
    <td>test td 3</td>
    <td>test td 4</td>
    <td>test td 5</td>
    <td>Click for content</td>
    <td>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pulvinar nisi sit amet luctus efficitur. Vivamus eu risus suscipit, ultricies tortor eu, sodales tellus. Sed sed feugiat massa. Cras mollis, erat eget pellentesque porttitor, mauris lectus ultricies neque, varius iaculis quam mi et quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc egestas nec mi eu lobortis. Nam eu scelerisque orci. Mauris vel ultricies dui, non accumsan turpis. Aliquam pulvinar in dolor sit amet fringilla. Integer sed quam pellentesque, volutpat arcu a, feugiat nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed auctor ac nulla sit amet suscipit.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rngapLze/

Comment: you set float: left for that cell what should be the expected output?

Comment: the last cell should be above all the other cells and occupy the table completely.

Comment: better set tooltip on that TD, and set ellipsis style for rounding text with "..."

Comment: You can set styling as overflow: scroll or hidden. you can even set max height and min height to td

Comment: you have to fix the width of that column..

Answer (score 0):

```css
tr td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="item-big" colspan="5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pulvinar nisi sit amet luctus efficitur. Vivamus eu risus suscipit, ultricies tortor eu, sodales tellus. Sed sed feugiat massa. Cras mollis, erat eget pellentesque porttitor, mauris
      lectus ultricies neque, varius iaculis quam mi et quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc egestas nec mi eu lobortis. Nam eu scelerisque orci. Mauris vel ultricies dui, non accumsan turpis. Aliquam pulvinar in dolor
      sit amet fringilla. Integer sed quam pellentesque, volutpat arcu a, feugiat nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed auctor ac nulla sit amet suscipit.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item0">test td 1</td>
    <td class="item1">test td 2</td>
    <td class="item2">test td 3</td>
    <td class="item3">test td 4</td>
    <td class="item4">test td 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to have the td within the same row